# PHP fgetcsv with line ending character

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have an oddly-formatted file I need to parse with PHP. It uses `^` as the field delimiter, and `~` as the end-of-line character. I can easily set the `$delimiter` param of `fgetcsv` to `^` to get most of the data.
The problem is that `fgetcsv` doesn't accept an EOL character as a parameter-- so it reads the lines based on line breaks rather than respecting the EOL character.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Do you have an example of this oddly formatted data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good old PHP, where people forget how to do stuff manually if there's some half-baked standard function available:

```
$lines = explode('~', file_get_contents($pathToMyFile));
foreach($lines as $line)
{
  $values = explode('^', $line);
}
```

Depending on the escape strategy (if `^` or `~` occur in values) you'd have to tweak this a bit.

Comment: @Niels-- very nice! Thanks for the reminder that functions can be more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: How big is the file then is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file, replace `~` with `\n`, then use `str_getcsv`:

```
$csv = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.csv');
$csv = str_replace('~','\n',$csv);
$csv = str_getcsv($csv, '^');
```